# Can't delete my first item in shopping basket

Tags: php, html, mysqli, project

Currently doing my computing science assignment and I've chosen to make an online shop, I've used a tutorial to make the shopping basket and everything is working except I can only delete every item except the first one added to my cart. I'd really appreciate any help if possible.

**This is where items in my cart are displayed (cart.php):**

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once('db.php'); 
include('common.php');
 ?>

 <?php getHeader(); ?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <table class="table">
            <?php 
                $items = $_SESSION['cart'];
                $cartitems = explode(",", $items);
            ?>

            <?php
                $total = '';
                $i=1;
                 foreach ($cartitems as $key=>$id) {
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = $id";
                    $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                    $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
            ?>      
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                    <td><a href="delcart.php?remove=<?php echo $key; ?>">Remove</a> <?php echo $r['name']; ?></td>
                    <td>£<?php echo $r['price']; ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php 
                $total = $total + $r['price'];
                $i++; 
                } 
            ?>

            <tr>
                <td><strong>Total Price</strong></td>
                <td><strong>£<?php echo $total; ?></strong></td>
                <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Checkout</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<?php getFooter(); ?>
```

**This is my code that adds an item to my cart(addtocart.php):**

```
    <?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['cart']) & !empty($_SESSION['cart'])){
    $items = $_SESSION['cart'];
    $cartitems = explode(",", $items);
    $items .= "," . $_GET['id'];
    $_SESSION['cart'] = $items;
    header('location: index.php?status=success');
}else{
    $items = $_GET['id'];
    $_SESSION['cart'] = $items;
    header('location: index.php?status=success');
}


if(in_array($_GET['id'], $cartitems)){
    header('location: index.php?status=incart');
}else{
    $items .= "," . $_GET['id'];
    $_SESSION['cart'] = $items;
    header('location: index.php?status=success');   
}   
?>
```

**This is my delete item code (delcart.php):**

```
<?php 
session_start();
$items = $_SESSION['cart'];
$cartitems = explode(",", $items);
if(($_GET['remove']) & !empty($_GET['remove'])){
    $delitem = $_GET['remove'];
    unset($cartitems[$delitem]);
    $itemids = implode(",", $cartitems);
    $_SESSION['cart'] = $itemids;
}
header('location:cart.php');
?>
```

Comment: Why do you store a comma-separated string in `$_SESSION['cart']` instead of an actual array? Then you don't need to keep exploding and imploding.

Comment: GET['remove'] that equals zero is considered __false__

Comment: Session BTW can store arrays without imploding to string.

Comment: @u_mulder Post that falsey explanation as an answer.

Comment: @Barmar I'm from mobile so it's a little complicated. Besides here are more errors like using & instead of &&.

Comment: Always `exit()` after `header('Location: ...');`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line:

```
if ($_GET['remove'] & !empty($_GET['remove']))
```

When you want to remove the first item, `$_GET['remove']` is `0`, which is falsey and also considered empty, so the code that's supposed to remove it doesn't run. Change it to:

```
if (isset($_GET['remove']) && is_numeric($_GET['remove']))
```

Also, throughout your scripts you're using `&` when you should be using `&&`. `&` is bit-wise AND, `&&` is logical AND.

Answer (score 1):

When you have only one item in your session,

```
$cartitems = explode(",", $items);
```

result is array with "0" index, so if you want to remove last value, $_GET['remove'] should be equal to "0" (example: www.site.loc/?remove=0)

I hope you show us only a sample (not production) code because it is very wrong written and dangerous example:

> $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = $id"; SHOULD NEVER BE USE!

Comment: The SQL can be used, it just needs to be sanitized first.

Comment: @MECU You are right, but also wrong. This example of SQL is an indication that the OP is not using prepared statements, which is a wrong way of doing SQL and should never be done.

Comment: @Dharman There's nothing wrong with using pure SQL. There's no requirement to prepare and bind. This is a homework/project, so while I agree your comment is helpful, as is r_a_f in the warning, I just wanted to indicate it can be used, if you take precautions. As you pointed out, one option is prepare and bind. There are others but "never be done" isn't true either.

Comment: @MECU There are plenty more wrong things which can be done, and doing them in the dark room behind closed doors without making the code public is acceptable e.g. writing malware. However, SO is aiming to teach proper coding practices. Concatenating SQL with data is the wrong, and should not be encouraged here.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things wrong with your code:

1) $_SESSION['cart'] appears to be a string of comma-separated `id`s, i.e. `string(10) "1, 2, 3, 4"`

Thus, `$cartitems = explode(",", $items)` would return an array of those ids, i.e. `array(4)[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]`

2) Assuming that `$_GET['remove']` is a string containing the item `id`, i.e. `3`

Calling `unset($cartitems[$delitem])` would remove the last element of my example array, `4`, since arrays are zero-indexed.

To remove the value `3` you'd have to call:

```
$delitem = array_search($_GET['remove'], $cartitems);
unset($cartitems[$delitem]);
```

(see http://php.net/array_search)

3) May I please suggest using PDO? http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Edit: since I can't comment, Barmar:

Given that OP's items are stored in a database, and `id` is likely a primary key, it's unlikely that he'd have an item with `id` of `0` so empty() should be perfectly suitable for his needs. To expound on that point, though, OP, Barmar is correct that in if there *are* in fact 0 based `id`s, you'd want to use `isset($_GET['remove'])` not `!empty($_GET['remove'])`

See http://php.net/isset and http://php.net/empty for differences.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop and then usage of the variables is the problem:

```
                 foreach ($cartitems as $key=>$id) {
...
                      <td><a href="delcart.php?remove=<?php echo $id; ?>">Remove</a> <?php echo $r['name']; ?></td>
...
                 }
```

The `$key` should be `$id`

When using `foreach` this way, the `$key` var is the array index and the `$id` is the value (which could be a string, array, object, int...).

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

But since you don't care about the array index here, you can simply omit it from the `foreach` declaration:

```
                 foreach ($cartitems as $id) {
```

and it will work identically.